# License verification - how to check server response safety

Tags: if-statement, reverse-engineering, reverse, license-key

I'm creating a License Generator & PC IDs based verification - program to create license based pc hardware.

It sends pc id ( such as mac address, uuid, bios serial number etc) to a server that create the license, and sends it back to the client.

When client wants to activate the program, he sends his license to the server and gets an answer – basically true or false.

All data encrypted by AES key and signed  by server….

**Here is the problem** – Can I make sure a reverser didn't change the code checks server's response? There is always this "if condition" ( or cmp in assembly) that can be changed

I took care of obfuscation, packing, anti-debugging etc, as much as I can, but a good reverser can change and pass it

Thank you

Avinoam

Answer (score 0):

Simply enough: that's impossible. As you said, there will always be some "if condition".

I'll just list some methods I remember that applications use to make it harder for crackers:

- checksums on the code. If a cracker will change some of the code, she'll also need to find the appropriate checksum (which can be further obfuscated)
- running multiple checks throughout the code, and possible in many threads/tasks at specific/random times (e.g verify the CDKEY every 1 minute via a different code path)
- have some of the code encrypted using the CDKEY (so if you don't have one, you don't really have the application's code at all)
- have the appropriate code stored on your sever. When the user tries to access a "new" feature (e.g next stage in a game), the application will handshake with the server, and if the server is convinced that it's not a cracker, the server will send the relevant code to the application, which will then run it.
- have a remote SIM-like device that is *physically* obfuscated (just like a SIM card) that will provide a *physical* API to the computer, and the server will query that device to check for its genuinity. Just read about SIM cards.